# How to remove all duplicates from a list and change all references to the duplicates with Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, reference, duplicates

I have a list of points that are referenced by walls and floors. After loading the points from a file into the list, I need to merge all of the identical points in the list, so that the walls and floors still reference the points in the list. I cannot save the points in the file due to limitation of another program that uses the same file.

Example:

```
# points just have x, y, z coordinates
# walls have two points, a and b

a = point(0, 0, 0)
b = point(1, 1, 1)
c = point(2, 2, 2)
walls = [wall(a, b), wall(b, c)]
points = [a, b, b, c] # this was loaded like so from the file that had the walls
```

I want `points` to be `[a, b, c]`, and the walls that reference point b have to reference the point b that is in `points`, and not some other point b with the same properties.

Every other solution just removes the duplicates but fails to change references to the duplicate, so I am left with walls that reference points that I cannot access.

Comment: use `set()` to remove duplicates?

Comment: and then convert back to list: `list(set(points))`

Comment: I tried that, but references to the duplicates were not changed to match the new point objects, but still used the removed duplicates.

Comment: if you create the point list like you show in your question, then both `b` entries in `points` point to the same object. To verify, you can do `[id(x) for x in points]`

Comment: I need the references in the wall objects to point to the same points, and sets don't seem to do that.